# SQL Server 2012 database stuck restoring

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

I'm trying to restore my development database DEV with a backup of my production database PROD. Every time I go through this process, the DEV database gets stuck in a Restoring state. Using the SQL "RESTORE DATABASE DEV WITH RECOVERY" does not break it out of the Restoring state. The only way I can get it out of that state is by using the Restore Database wizard. I have generated a script from that wizard and, with the exception of the SINGLE_USER and MULTI_USER lines, the SQL is the same as what I'm using below.

```
USE [master]

ALTER DATABASE DEV SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE

RESTORE DATABASE DEV
FROM DISK = N'D:\Backup\PROD-20160629.bak'
WITH FILE = 1,
MOVE N'PROD' TO N'D:\Data\DEV.mdf',
MOVE N'PROD_log' TO N'D:\Logs\DEV.ldf',
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5

ALTER DATABASE DEV SET MULTI_USER
```

Why does my database get stuck in a Restoring state from this statement?

Comment: If you just want to restore the database from the bak file and not apply any transaction logs, use `WITH RECOVERY`. You could use that in place of `NOUNLOAD` - why do restore statements still have this thing from the 1990s?